# Why do I get an error that Sagemaker Endpoint does not have multiple models when it does?

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

Invoking a multimodel Sagemaker Endpoint, I get an error that it is not multimodel. I create it like this.

```
create_endpoint_config_response = client.create_endpoint_config(
    EndpointConfigName=endpoint_config_name,
    ProductionVariants=[
        {
            "InstanceType": "ml.m5.large",
            "InitialVariantWeight": 0.5,
            "InitialInstanceCount": 1,
            "ModelName": model_name1,
            "VariantName": model_name1,
        },
         {
            "InstanceType": "ml.m5.large",
            "InitialVariantWeight": 0.5,
            "InitialInstanceCount": 1,
            "ModelName": model_name2,
            "VariantName": model_name2,
        }
    ]
)
```

I confirm in the GUI that it in fact has multiple models. I invoke it like this:

```
response = client.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName=endpoint_name, 
    TargetModel=model_name1,
    ContentType="text/x-libsvm", 
    Body=payload
)
```

and get this error:

> ValidationError: An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the
> InvokeEndpoint operation: Endpoint
> my-endpoint1 is not a multi-model endpoint
> and does not support target model header.

The same problem was discussed [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/1026) with no resolution.

How can I invoke a multimodel endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer (see [GitHub](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/1026) discussion) is that this error message is simply false.

To avoid this error, the model's local filename (usually for the form `model_filename.tar.gz`) must be used, not the model name.

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/invoke-multi-model-endpoint.html) does say this, though it lacks essential detail.

I found [this to be the best example](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/multi_model_xgboost_home_value/xgboost_multi_model_endpoint_home_value.ipynb).  See the last part  of that Notebook, in which `invoke_endpoint` is used (rather than a predictor as used earlier in the Notebook).

As to the location of that model file: This [Notebook](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/multi_model_bring_your_own/multi_model_endpoint_bring_your_own.ipynb) says:

> When creating the Model entity for multi-model endpoints, the container's ModelDataUrl is the S3 prefix where the model
> artifacts that are invokable by the endpoint are located. The rest of the S3 path will be specified when invoking the model.